# Passing a UIImage from one view controller to a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, uitableview

I am using a UITable to show images (Like a feed in instagram) I have the image saved in the viewcontroller I am taking the picture, but I need a way to pass the UIImage i have created to the UITableViewCell. What would be the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Means you want to pass UITableView image to another view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subclass UITableViewCell and give it a public property like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *thumbnailImage;
```

then in your uitableviewcells implementation file create and add a UIImageView however you want.

```
- (void)setThumbnailImage:(UIImage *)thumbnailImage
{
   _thumbnailImage = thumbnailImage;
   self.imageView.image = _thumbnailImage;
}
```

in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, do something like

```
cell.thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageNamed:"YourImage.png"];
```

This is just one of many ways to do this.